# How do I round up a Decimal to the nearest 1000 in Apex code?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, decimal, rounding

I have a Visualforce PDF page with decimal values in it and these need to be rounded to the nearest 1000.00. If I do `decimal x = Math.round(x)` it just takes it to the nearest value on the left.

Eg I have

- 1,243,478.80 and need it rounded up to 1,243,000.00
- 1,243,578.80 and need it rounded up to 1,244,000.00

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decimal class has the `setScale()` method. It's usually used to set the number of decimal places to be used, but you can pass it a negative number to round to the nearest 10, 100, 1000, etc...

```
Decimal d = 1234.56;
system.debug(d.setScale(-3)); // 1000
system.debug(d.setScale(-3, RoundingMode.CEILING)); // 2000
```

Comment: Nifty. I learned something new today (I don't work with decimals often).

Comment: @Derek F if I use your method and run it the debug returns this 'DEBUG|1E+3' - do I need to reformat or something to get it to display as a decimal?

Comment: @Irene It still is a decimal. The scientific notation is just an artifact of serialization that happens when `system.debug()` is called

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Derek. How do I see the actual number in Debug?

Comment: @Irene In general, you shouldn't worry too much about how `system.debug` displays things. '1E+3' is precisely the same as '1000'. If it is an issue in your PDF/Visualforce, then you could cast it as an `Integer` after rounding to the nearest target value.

Answer (score 2):

To get the *nearest* thousand, divide by 1000, round, and then multiply by 1000:

```
Decimal y = (x/1000).round()*1000;
```

To get the *next highest* thousand (towards positive infinity), you can round up:

```
Decimal y = (x/1000).round(RoundingMode.CEILING)*1000;
```

You can also read more about [RoundingMode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_decimal_rounding_mode) for other options, such as rounding away from zero.

Comment: Great - works like a charm